# How to get files metadata, when retrieving data from HDFS?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

I requested data from HDFS, and I would like to get the metadata of the files from which they were read.
This will allow me to build reports which will look like based on available data at the given moment.

I found the solution which is to use `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem` to get a listing of all files.
I know the partitioning rule, and I can build mapping `row -> meta`, based on the received listing.

But this decision seems difficult to implement and support. Maybe there are simpler ways to achieve the same result?

Comment: can you add code snippet whatever you found solution which is to use org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem to get listing of all files ?

Comment: No, I can't. It's only guess

Comment: What about `hdfs fsck <path> -files -blocks -locations`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way to do so is with spark udf `input_file_name`.

```scala
import scala.collection.mutable.Map
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}

val df = spark.read.text("<path>").withColumn("input_file_name", input_file_name()).repartition($"input_file_name")

def getMetadata(rdd: Iterator[Row]) = {
    val map = Map[String, Long]()
    val fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration())
    rdd.map(row => {
                val path = row.getString(row.size -1)
                if(! map.contains(path)){
                    map.put(path,fs.listStatus(new Path(path))(0).getModificationTime())
                }
                Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq ++ Array[Any](map(path)))
            })
}

spark.createDataFrame(df.rdd.mapPartitions(getMetadata),df.schema.add("modified_ts", LongType)).show(10000,false)
```

Here `modified_ts` is the `mtime` for the file.

Depending on size of the data, you can also do it with join. The logic will look something like:

```scala
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val mtime =(path:String)=> FileSystem.get(new Configuration()).listStatus(new Path(path)).head.getModificationTime
val mtimeUDF = udf(mtime)

val df = spark.read.text("<path>").withColumn("input_file_name", input_file_name())

val metadata_df = df.select($"input_file_name").distinct().withColumn("mtime", mtimeUDF($"input_file_name"))

val rows_with_metadata = df.join(metadata_df , "input_file_name")
rows_with_metadata.show(false)
```

Comment: Do you mean that after receiving the file name, I can also find out the time of its creation?

Comment: Definitely. You can then use `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem` to know timestamp creation date.

Comment: Can you help me to write the next line? `.withColumn("modificationTime", ???)` 

It seems like I can't call a `FileSystem` method from here

Comment: For each row you are invoking HDFS FileSystem to get metadata, Check the performance if you have millions of data. I think this is not good idea to invoke fs on every row of DataFrame

Comment: @BanyRule, we need a UDF/mapPartiitons after this point. Let me get back to you with some more directions. Which language are you using with spark?

Comment: Good point @Srinivas, something I had in my mind but had to be stated. I have implemented a few bits to take care of this.

Answer (score 5):

I have create small helper method `metadata`, you can directly invoke on DataFrame object like `df.metadata`, It will create DataFrame on available metadata & return DataFrame back.

**Meta Columns in final DataFrame**

- path
- isDirectory
- length           -- will be displayed human readable format 47 bytes
- replication
- blockSize        -- will be displayed human readable format 47 bytes
- modificationTime -- This will be converted from unix time to normal datetime.
- accessTime
- owner
- group
- permission
- isSymlink

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

  import org.joda.time.DateTime
  import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
  import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
  import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, LocatedFileStatus, Path, RemoteIterator}

  // Storing Metadata
  case class FileMetaData(path: String,
                          isDirectory:Boolean,
                          length:String,
                          replication:Int,
                          blockSize:String,
                          modificationTime: String,
                          accessTime:String ,
                          owner:String ,
                          group:String ,
                          permission:String,
                          isSymlink:Boolean)

  object FileMetaData {

    def apply(lfs: LocatedFileStatus):FileMetaData = {        
      new FileMetaData(
        path= lfs.getPath.toString,
        isDirectory=lfs.isDirectory,
        length=FileUtils.byteCountToDisplaySize(lfs.getLen),
        replication=lfs.getReplication,
        blockSize=FileUtils.byteCountToDisplaySize(lfs.getBlockSize),
        modificationTime=new DateTime(lfs.getModificationTime).toString,
        accessTime=new DateTime(lfs.getAccessTime).toString ,
        owner=lfs.getOwner ,
        group=lfs.getGroup ,
        permission=lfs.getPermission.toString,
        isSymlink=lfs.isSymlink
      )
    }
  }

  // Convert RemoteIterator to Scala Iterator.
  implicit def convertToScalaIterator[T](remoteIterator: RemoteIterator[T]): Iterator[T] = {
    case class wrapper(remoteIterator: RemoteIterator[T]) extends Iterator[T] {
      override def hasNext: Boolean = remoteIterator.hasNext
      override def next(): T = remoteIterator.next()
    }
    wrapper(remoteIterator)
  }

  // Using this we can call metadata method on df - like df.metadata.
  implicit class MetaData(df: DataFrame) {
    def metadata =  {
      import df.sparkSession.implicits._
       df.inputFiles.map(new Path(_))
         .flatMap{
           FileSystem
             .get(df.sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
             .listLocatedStatus(_)
             .toList
       }
         .map(FileMetaData(_)).toList.toDF
     }
  }

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

warning: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, LocatedFileStatus, Path, RemoteIterator}
defined class FileMetaData
defined object FileMetaData
convertToScalaIterator: [T](remoteIterator: org.apache.hadoop.fs.RemoteIterator[T])Iterator[T]
defined class MetaData

scala> val df = spark.read.format("json").load("/tmp/data")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [json_data: struct<value: string>]



scala> df.show(false)
+------------------+
|json_data         |
+------------------+
|[{"a":1} ,{"b":2}]|
|[{"a":1} ,{"b":2}]|
|[{"a":1} ,{"b":2}]|
+------------------+

scala>
```

**DataFrame Metadata Output**

```
scala> df.metadata.show(false)

+-------------------------+-----------+--------+-----------+---------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+--------+-----+----------+---------+
|path                     |isDirectory|length  |replication|blockSize|modificationTime             |accessTime                   |owner   |group|permission|isSymlink|
+-------------------------+-----------+--------+-----------+---------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+--------+-----+----------+---------+
|file:/tmp/data/fileB.json|false      |47 bytes|1          |32 MB    |2020-04-25T13:47:00.000+05:30|1970-01-01T05:30:00.000+05:30|srinivas|wheel|rw-r--r-- |false    |
|file:/tmp/data/fileC.json|false      |47 bytes|1          |32 MB    |2020-04-25T13:47:10.000+05:30|1970-01-01T05:30:00.000+05:30|srinivas|wheel|rw-r--r-- |false    |
|file:/tmp/data/fileA.json|false      |47 bytes|1          |32 MB    |2020-04-25T11:35:12.000+05:30|1970-01-01T05:30:00.000+05:30|srinivas|wheel|rw-r--r-- |false    |
+-------------------------+-----------+--------+-----------+---------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+--------+-----+----------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I can make a guess try to debug the code:

```
hdfs debug computeMeta -block <block-file> -out <output-metadata-file>
```

you can find your command kindly visit https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSCommands.html#verifyMeta