# Spark check if input path with regex exists

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to read JSON files under a path that is computed using regex like below.

```
paths.par.foreach
{ 
    path =>
    val pathWithRegex = s"${path}/*/${dateRegex}/"
    val jsonDF = sqlContext.read.json(pathWithRegex)
}
```

```
paths could be - hdfs://servername/data/a, hdfs://servername/data/b, hdfs://servername/data/c
dateRegex could be - 2020-05-*

Directories present in hdfs
hdfs://servername/data/a/something/2020-05-11/file1
hdfs://servername/data/a/something/2020-05-12/file1
hdfs://servername/data/b/something/2020-05-11/file1
hdfs://servername/data/c/something/2020-06-11/file1
```

When I pass 2020-05-* as dateRegex, it is throwing error
for hdfs://servername/data/c/*/2020-05-*/ as Path doesn't exist.
Is there a way to not throw error and proceed?
I tried using below checkDirExist method but it doesn't seem to work
for regex/pattern.

```
def checkDirExist(path: String, sc:SparkContext): Boolean = {
    val fs = FileSystem.get(sc.hadoopConfiguration)
    val p = new Path(path)
    fs.exists(p)
}

paths.par.foreach
{ 
    path =>
    val pathWithRegex = s"${path}/*/${dateRegex}/"
    if(checkDirExist(pathWithRegex, sc)){ //Doesn't work. Always false if pattern is in path string
        val jsonDF = sqlContext.read.json(pathWithRegex)
    }
}
```

Comment: could you share your input and output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check below code.

below code will work for `hdfs`,`s3` & `local filesystem`.

Importing required libraries.

```
import  scala.util.matching.Regex
import java.net.URI
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path, RemoteIterator}
```

For converting to scala Iterator

```
implicit def convertToScalaIterator[T](remoteIterator: RemoteIterator[T]): Iterator[T] = {
    case class wrapper(remoteIterator: RemoteIterator[T]) extends Iterator[T] {
      override def hasNext: Boolean = remoteIterator.hasNext
      override def next(): T = remoteIterator.next()
    }
    wrapper(remoteIterator)
}
```

List of available directories & files.

```
import sys.process._
scala> "tree /root/tmp/servername".!
/root/tmp/servername
└── data
    ├── a
    │   └── something
    │       ├── 2020-05-11
    │       │   └── file1
    │       └── 2020-05-12
    │           └── file1
    ├── b
    │   └── something
    │       └── 2020-05-11
    │           └── file1
    └── c
        └── something
            └── 2020-06-11
                └── file1

11 directories, 4 files
```

Getting`FileSystem` object

```
def getFs(spark:SparkSession): String => FileSystem = (path: String) => {
    FileSystem.get(URI.create(path),spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
}
val fs = getFs(spark)
```

Function to check the files available in given path & return path of files matching regex pattern.

```
def exists(path: String,find:Regex)(fs: String => FileSystem) = { 
    fs(path)
    .listFiles(new Path(path),true)
    .toList.filter(_.isFile)
    .map(_.getPath)
    .filter(c => find.findAllIn(c.toString).length != 0)   
}
val fileList = exists("/root/tmp/servername","2020-05-*".r)(fs)
```

Final Output

```
scala> fileList.foreach(println)
file:/root/tmp/servername/data/b/something/2020-05-11/file1
file:/root/tmp/servername/data/a/something/2020-05-11/file1
file:/root/tmp/servername/data/a/something/2020-05-12/file1
```

To get metadata your files, Check this post - [df.metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61317600/how-to-get-files-metadata-when-retrieving-data-from-hdfs)