# Is there any way to add modified timestamp of the source file as an additional column?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I want to find out the latest value for each given key, and I don't have any timestamp in the original dataset to go by, so I'd like to tap into the file modification timestamp on HDFS and would like to only select the row that appears last in those files.

Is there any way to do this with Spark Structured Streaming?

Comment: Check this - to get file metadata https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61317600/how-to-get-files-metadata-when-retrieving-data-from-hdfs/61423874#61423874