# List local filesystem using HDFS lister Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, filesystems, hdfs

I have functionality for listing files in directories in HDFS. I would like to list local directories files in my unit tests so how can I switch configuration to the local file system?
This is how I use it now in tests:

```
val filesClient = new MockFilesClient(spark().sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration) //parameter i need to replace
filesClient.list(any[String]) returns List(samplePath)
```

The method itself:

```
class MockFilesClient(localFsConfig: Configuration){

  def list(path: String): List[String] = {
    listPath(new Path(path.toString), recursive = true)(localFsConfig)
      .toList
  }.map(p => p.toString)
}
```

Comment: Check this post & change logic as per your requirement - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61317600/how-to-get-files-metadata-when-retrieving-data-from-hdfs/61423874#61423874

Comment: @Srinivas, Exactly I searched for the above post of yours, finally you posted it. is there any efficient way to store all the useful questions in bookmarsk, since SO bookmarks is some what hard to use it for me.

Comment: Yes, go to that question and click on star ⭐ mark under the downvote..it will available in your profile under bookmarks tab... Please upvote if it helps :)