# List files in directory (including file information) with Scala/Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs, apache-zeppelin

I'm pretty new to Scala/Spark and I hope you guys can help me. I want to get the files which were created after a certain timestamp in a directory of a hdfs for a little monitoring in Zeppelin. Therefore I need a column with the file name , the file size and the modificationDate.

I found this is working for me to get all the information I need:

```
val fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration())
val dir: String = "some/hdfs/path"
val input_files = fs.listStatus(new Path(dir)).filter(_.getModificationTime> timeInEpoch)
```

With the result I would like to create a DataFrame in spark with a row for each file with its information (or at least the information mentioned above)

```
val data = sc.parallelize(input_files) 
val dfFromData2 = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF()
```

If I try it this way I get the following response:

```
309: error: overloaded method value createDataFrame with alternatives:
  [A <: Product](data: Seq[A])(implicit evidence$3: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[A])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  [A <: Product](rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[A])(implicit evidence$2: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[A])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
 cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus])
       val dfFromData2 = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF()
```

I hope you can help me out :)

Greetings

Comment: Check this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61317600/how-to-get-files-metadata-when-retrieving-data-from-hdfs/61423874#61423874

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message indicates, the Hadoop `FileStatus` type is not a subtype of `Product`, i.e. a Tuple. Spark DataFrames have their own SQL-style type system which doesn't allow for arbitrary, complex types like `FileStatus`. Likewise, if you were to attempt an operation on the RDD you created you would receive a similar error as `FileStatus` is not serializable. Your best bet is to extract the data you need as a tuple or case class and create a DataFrame from that:

```
case class FileInfo(name : String, modifiedTime : Long, size : Long)

val df = input_files.map{x => 
           FileInfo(x.getPath.toString, x.getModificationTime, x.getLen)
        }.toSeq.toDF()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is exactly what I was looking for