# How to get Spark written part files shared unique ID?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

When using spark writing methods, for me it's specifically `saveAsTable(table, partitionBy, path)` inside AWS Glue environment, spark writes files of the following type:

```
part-00001-d2198eb8-db9f-4f8a-8dbe-63fb1ddc0cff.c000.snappy.parquet
part-00025-d2198eb8-db9f-4f8a-8dbe-63fb1ddc0cff.c000.snappy.parquet
part-00067-d2198eb8-db9f-4f8a-8dbe-63fb1ddc0cff.c000.snappy.parquet
```

So the syntax is the following:

```
part-<partition_id>-<write_id>.c000.<compression_and_extension>
```

**Can anyone suggest, how the retrieve the `<write_id>` before from any job metadata either before or after the job run during the application runtime?**

Also it would be useful to know when `c000` part is actually changed and if I need to expect it to change.

---

I need this to be able to backtrack later the specific job run to the list of files that was written by this job. Due to highly nested partitioning structure and other reasons I need some reliable way to find all file output names in advance.

Please do not suggest doing manual listing of the written files and getting it using regex, it's obvious and not useful for the use-case that I have.

From my tries, application ID is not it and job logs do not have any mention of it, so any other guesses or precise information are highly appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify - you have multiple jobs writing to the same S3-Prefix and want to be able to identify which job wrote the file?

Comment: @Maurice yes, exactly

Comment: do you want write_id of existing files or new files ? - You can get the metadata of existing files before job run and once job done then get the metadata & compare it with previous.. - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61317600/how-to-get-files-metadata-when-retrieving-data-from-hdfs/61423874#61423874

Comment: Can you just write the job name into a column? That in combination with the meta-column `$path` would allow you to use e.g. Athena to figure out which files belong to a job. Since the data is stored as parquet, the storage overhead should be negligible.

Comment: @Srinivas I want UUID of the files yet to be written. unfortunately the proposed link do not solve my issue, it's involves additional computation and related to source files, not target ones

Comment: ok, what are you going to do with UUID of files yet to be written ?

Comment: @Maurice storing job_id can be a solution for specific table, but I need to be able to analyse all existing jobs and tables, also changing the schema of each of those table will require significant time.