# Identifying Files with Extensions Using Wildcards

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

After mounting my data lake to Databricks, I attempt to load all JSON files into a dataframe using `*.json` suffix but it is not working:

```
df = spark.read.option("recursiveFileLookup", "true") \
    .json("/mnt/adls_gen/prod/**/*.json")
```

I get below error when executing the above code

```
[PATH_NOT_FOUND] Path does not exist: dbfs:/mnt/adls_gen/prod/**/*.json.
```

If I remove the file extension, the operation succeeds:

```
df = spark.read.option("recursiveFileLookup", "true") \
    .json("/mnt/adls_gen/prod/**/*")
```

...but it is also reading other files, such as files with extensions `*.json_old` and `*.txt`.

I'm unfamiliar with any alternative options to use in this scenario. Is there another method available for filtering by file extension? My files in the data lake have various extensions, so I'm seeking a solution that accommodates this diversity.

Apache Spark version is 3.4.1 (Scala 2.12).

Comment: Are you getting error? what are you expecting?

Comment: when I use path "/mnt/adls_gen/prod/**/*.json" I am getting error that no path exists.
and if I use "/mnt/adls_gen/prod/**/*" then it is loading unwanted files as well.

Comment: May be you can get all required files using this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61317600/how-to-get-files-metadata-when-retrieving-data-from-hdfs/61423874#61423874 then pass it to spark.read.json(..)

Comment: see if there is any character in your path. space or extra `.` at the end.

Comment: My theory is that `/mnt/adls_gen/prod/*/*` is not the last layer of directories in data lake. You're reading a series of folders that are second to last in directory hierarchy, and that's why when you try to read `/mnt/adls_gen/prod/**/*.json`, you get the error that the path doesn't exist (It's because the folders don't have `.json` in their names. Try out `/mnt/adls_gen/prod/*/*/*.json`, and the `.txt` and `.json_old` files will be excluded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought that was the purpose of having a [Path Glob Filter](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.4.1/sql-data-sources-generic-options.html#path-glob-filter) among other generic file source options:

> **Path Glob Filter**
>  `pathGlobFilter` is used to only include files with
> file names matching the pattern. The syntax follows
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.GlobFilter. It does not change the behavior of
> partition discovery.

```
df_filtered = spark.read
  .option("header","true")
  .option("recursiveFileLookup","true")
  .csv("s3a://mybucket/testdata/csvs", pathGlobFilter="*.csv")

from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df_filtered.select(input_file_name()).distinct().show(truncate=False)
+-------------------------------------+
|input_file_name()                    |
+-------------------------------------+
|s3a://mybucket/testdata/csvs/c000.csv|
|s3a://mybucket/testdata/csvs/c001.csv|
|         :         :          :      |
+-------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Great, thanks, this pathGlobFilter="*.json" worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use the `path` for providing prefix patterns:

I have tried the below approach:

```
df = spark.read.option("recursiveFileLookup", "true") \
    .schema(schema) \
    .option("basePath", "abfss://folder02@strgdilip.dfs.core.windows.net/") \
    .json("abfss://folder02@strgdilip.dfs.core.windows.net/*.json") \
    .cache()
filtered_df = df.where(input_file_name().like("%.json"))
filtered_df.show()
```

**Results:**

```
+--------+----+--------+--------------------+----------+----------+--------------------+
|    name| age|    city|               email|is_student|     title|               tasks|
+--------+----+--------+--------------------+----------+----------+--------------------+
|    NULL|NULL|    NULL|                NULL|      NULL|To-Do List|[{Buy groceries, ...|
|John Doe|  30|New York|john.doe@example.com|     false|      NULL|                NULL|
+--------+----+--------+--------------------+----------+----------+--------------------+
```

In the above code  reading the **JSON** files with the defined schema and base path
Apply the filter on the cached DataFrame

You know more [Filtering directories or files using glob patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/ingestion/auto-loader/patterns)

I agree with @Accrow  and I also have tried the below approach

```
df = spark.read.option("recursiveFileLookup", "true") \
.schema(schema) \
.json("abfss://folder02@strgdilip.dfs.core.windows.net/*/*.json")
df.show()
```

```
+--------+----+--------+--------------------+----------+----------+--------------------+
|    name| age|    city|               email|is_student|     title|               tasks|
+--------+----+--------+--------------------+----------+----------+--------------------+
|    NULL|NULL|    NULL|                NULL|      NULL|To-Do List|[{Buy groceries, ...|
|John Doe|  30|New York|john.doe@example.com|     false|      NULL|                NULL|
+--------+----+--------+--------------------+----------+----------+--------------------+
```