# How to get latest modified file using scala from a folder in HDFS

Tags: scala

being pretty new to **Scala** can any one please kindly help me with a scenario where I need to get the file with latest modified date.

There are two scenarios. consider 2 directories ,

- **dir1** (which has sub directories and files present inside each sub directory )
- **dir2** (no sub directories but has only files )

for Scenario 1 - I need to get the file with latest modified date inside a latest modified date directory

for Scenario 2 - I just need the latest file with latest modified.

Please do help me in any way possible, I tried experiments with **java.io** file handling but haven't made any good progress.

[image: adding the code I tried]

Comment: This is too general to answer here; can you give a more specific example of the problems you found? Is it the Scala coding, the algorithm, or the Java libraries themselves?

Comment: I need the scala code for scenario 1

Comment: This isn't a code-writing site. If have tried and have found a specific problem then post it here, but if you haven't tried then check the documentation for `java.io.File` and, in particular, the `isDirectory`, `listFiles`, and `lastModified` methods. You will also need the Scala `maxByOption` method on a collection. A recursive function is probably the cleanest solution for nested directories.

Comment: Added the image of code above in question I tried to get the max time , but how to get the file which has that modified time ? should I iterate again checking each file modified time or is there any better way ?

Comment: That code should already be returning the `File`, not the time.

Comment: Also, you should include the code as text rather than an image. If you put four spaces at the start of each line it will automatically format it as code (see my answer, for example)

Comment: Check this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61317600/how-to-get-files-metadata-when-retrieving-data-from-hdfs/61423874#61423874 and filter by modified date.

Answer (score 0):

This is my (untested) code to perform this operation on nested directories:

```
def latest(file: File): File =
  file.listFiles.maxByOption(_.lastModified) match {
    case Some(f) => latest(f)
    case None => file
  }
```

This is tail recursive and will compile to a simple loop.

Comment: Sure , let me try and test/modify the snippet provided

Comment: The original will fail on an empty directory (infinite recursion) so I've replaced it with a better option. This assumes that `listFiles` on something that isn't a directory returns an empty list rather than throwing an error. The documentation is unclear on this.

Comment: Yup Thanks!! let me get back once trying on my folders.